# Using $this when not in object context - PHP

Tags: php

He explorado diversas preguntas similares antes de enviar esta publicación, así que estoy seguro de lo que estoy haciendo.

Estoy creando una aplicación web escrita en PHP, en donde, tengo algunas clases que suelo llamar, como por ejemplo utilizando `Url::exists($alias)`.

Pues bien, estoy consiguiendo el error `using $this when not in object context`, y no he podido resolverlo. Ya son más de 2 horas buscando una solución.

Código:

```
class Url extends App {

private $db;
private static $alias = null;
private static $list = null;
private static $url = null;
private static $clicks = 0;
private static $name = null;
private static $password = null;

public function __construct() {
$this->db = json_decode(file_get_contents('/../' . $this->getConfig()->get('DB_PATH')), true);
}

public static function exists(string $alias) {
foreach($this->db as $url) {
 if($url['ALIAS'] == $alias) {
  return true;
 }
}
return false;
}
```

En donde el error se encuentra en la línea `$this->db`.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: El error se debe a que estás llamando: `$this->getConfig()` pero no veo el método `getConfig()` en tu clase. Si el mismo se encuentra en la clase `App` asegúrate de que no es un método estático y de que estás incluyendo dicha clase.

Comment: El problema persiste. `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/u652566047/public_html/app/classes/Url.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /home/u652566047/public_html/app/classes/App.php(31): Url::exists('index.php') #1 /home/u652566047/public_html/app/autoload.php(24): App->run() #2 /home/u652566047/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/u65256604...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/u652566047/public_html/app/classes/Url.php on line 32`

Comment: Por cierto, no instancié. Utilizo `Url::exists($alias)`.

Comment: Persiste porque en alguna parte estás llamando con `$this` algo que no existe en el contexto de la clase. Sea porque no está incluido o porque no existe. El `getConfig()` llama a su vez a un método `get`  ¿es otro método de la clase `App`?

Comment: Tienes que instanciar mediante `new` previo `include`  o `require`  del archivo php de la clase,  a menos que estás cargando las clases con `Autoloader`

Answer (score 3):

`$this` se refiere al contexto *de la instancia actual del objecto*. Los metodos `static` *no pertencen a la instancia del objeto*.

Tienes 2 opciones:

1- Agregas el objeto a la instancia de clase removiendo el `static` de la declaracion del metodo:

```
 class Url extends App {

    public function exists(string $alias) {
      foreach($this->db as $url) {
       if($url['ALIAS'] == $alias) {
          return true;
        }  
     }
}
```

2- Le envias la instancia del objeto como parametro para obtener las propiedades del objecto que necesites:

```
class Url extends App {
         // ..

    public static function exists(Url $urlInstance, string $alias) {
      foreach($urlInstance->db as $url) {
       if($url['ALIAS'] == $alias) {
          return true;
        }  
     }
}
```

Uso:

```
$url = new Url();
Url::exists($url,"ruta");
```